# How to insert rows dynamically

Tags: sql, dynamic, sql-insert

I want to insert new rows in between existing rows in an existing table in SQL. For something like below table..

---

name :  entries

abc :      2
xyz :      3

Basically when entries says 2, i want to add two rows below that record, and when entries says 3 i would like to add 3 rows below that record. How can i do this dynamically in SQL?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

There is no significance to the "ordering of the rows" in an SQL table, meaning "ordering of the rows" is a nonexistent concept in SQL, meaning there is also no "inserting in between rows" or "inserting after this or that precise row" or any such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All,

But i figured it out on my own, :) yes there's no magical command to insert rows dynamically. I used recursiveCTE (Common table expression) and got what i wanted.

Thanks